# "configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed": How do I know why this happened?

Tags: nginx

I'm an nginx noob trying out this [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) tutorial on nginx 1.1.19 on ubuntu 12.04. I have [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9474452) nginx config file.

When I run this command the test fails:

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/csv" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

How do I know why the nginx.conf test failed?

Comment: Do you still have "default" in your "/etc/ngix/sites-enabled"?

Comment: @RickyA do you mean the "default" file? Yes, I still have that file located in that directory. I moved that file and ran nginx -s reload and still see the same behavior from the server

Comment: the error mentions the file csv, check that file in sites-enabled

Comment: Ad `sudo service nginx restart`) Nginx has a CLI tool as well: `nginx -s reload` to reload the config in case it changed. That's much faster.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

`sudo nginx -t` should test all files and return errors and warnings locations

Comment: it is testing only one file i.e: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but how can I test sites-enabled/default?

Comment: it think it would test all, as long as they are included in the default file ( which I assume they are ? ), if you are not using the default config file path then try using `-c` flag, so `nginx -c /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default -t`

Comment: Can confirm what @MohammadAbuShady said. Although the manpage for `-t` somewhat vaguely says *Don't run, just test the configuration file. The nginx checks configuration for correct syntax and then tries to open files referred in configuration.* the files are not just checked for existence but parsed. As expected the exit code is 1 if error found and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 28):

This particular commands worked for me.
`sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx nginx-full nginx-common`

and
`sudo apt-get install nginx`

credit to this answer on [stackexchnage](https://serverfault.com/questions/317191/how-to-install-nginx-and-install-the-configuration-files-too/317192#317192?newreg=04654e05fc854d36bfe307765ae15216)

Answer (score 6):

The first solution is to test nginx conf using the basic

```py
sudo nginx -t
```

Secondly, if you've changed the file yourself, copy/pasted json from one to another, there's a high chance that there's an encoding issue.

For example: `"` is not the same as

```py
``
```

Try to write configurations by yourself. Check commas, colon and braces. Don't forget to reload the nginx.

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check syntax error for any nginx files, you can use the -c option.

```
[root@server ~]# sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/my-server.conf
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/my-server.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/my-server.conf test is successful
[root@server ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be the fact that the path `/var/log/nginx/` does not exist. In my case someone deleted part of that path and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` was not able to populate . When I restored the path, I was able to get all tests cleared (checked with `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) and start nginx again.

Answer (score -1):

Show file and track error

```
 systemctl status nginx.service
```